# Can I bake 1 round of puff pastry on top of another

Tags: baking

Can I put 2 layers of puff pastry ( 1 on top of the other ) on top of a dish to make it very high ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you might want to use an eggwash or water to make sure the two layers stick together.

You'll want to be careful about **not** brushing near the edge -- if it drips down, it'll glue the side together preventing it from puffing properly

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there are recipes that call for exactly that.